# Zend_Search_Lucene - weird behaviour for Wildcard search and "numeric" string

Tags: string, zend-framework, integer, wildcard, zend-search-lucene

Weird issue I get every time I search "11.11" or "22.22" etc... No problem if I search for "aa.aa" but when I put only integers into my string, I get the following exception:

> Wildcard search is supported only for non-multiple word terms

My implementation of Zend search is as below (ZF 1.11):

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard::setMinPrefixLength(0);

Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8Num_CaseInsensitive()
);

$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../var/search');

if(str_word_count($searchQuery) > 1){

    $searchQuery = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::escape($searchQuery);

    $searchQueryArray = explode(' ', $searchQuery);
    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Phrase($searchQueryArray);
}else{

    $searchQuery = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::escape($searchQuery);

    $query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse(
        'title:*'.$searchQuery.'* OR
        description:*'.$searchQuery.'* OR 
        content:*'.$searchQuery.'*'
    );
}

$result = $index->find($query);
```

I can't really find any related issue on internet so please, let me know if you've ever been in front of the similar issue. Thank you.